# How to efficiently append running sum in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I'm writing a python script that uses a model to predict a large number of values by groupID, where **efficiency is important** (N on the order of 10^8). I initialize a results matrix and am trying to sequentially update a running sum of values in the results matrix.

Trying to be efficient, in my current method I use groupID as row numbers of the results matrix to avoid merging (merging is expensive, as far as I understand).

My attempt:

```
import numpy as np

# Initialize results matrix
results = np.zeros((5,3)) # dimension: number of groups x timestep

# Now I loop over batches, with batch size 4. Here's an example of one iteration:
batch_groupIDs = [3,1,0,1] # Note that multiple values can be generated for same groupID
batch_results = np.ones((4,3))

# My attempt at appending the results (low dimension example):
results[batch_groupIDs] += batch_results

print(results)
```

This outputs:

```
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

My desired output is the following (since group 1 shows up twice, and should be appended twice):

```
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [2. 2. 2.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

The actual dimensions of my problem are approximately 100 timesteps x a batch size of 1 million+ and 2000 groupIDs

Comment: With repeated indices, you want to use an unbuffered version of `np.add`.  `np.add.at`

Comment: @hpaulj - this looks exactly right! Then all I need to do is change the assignment line to np.add.at(results,batch_groupIDs,batch_results). I'll try to take a closer look at the proposed answers below to see if they're faster, but np.add.at() seems like the simplest option

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding, and please correct me if I'm wrong:

We want a resultant matrix that has the shape `number of groups x timestep` which in this case would be `2000 x 100`. This matrix needs to be efficiently updated sequentially for a batch size of 10^6.

If the summary is correct, here is my approach. We divide the 10^6 sequences into let's say *"mini-batches"* of 10^4 each. Another assumption is that the timesteps are weighted equally across all groups. :

1. Convert `batch_groupIDs` to a numpy array of frequencies. For `batch_groupIDs = [3,1,0,1]`, the array would look like `[1,2,0,1,0]`.
2. Convert the `timestep` values to numpy array. For `batch_results = np.ones((4,3))`, timestep array would look like `[1,1,1]` since 3 steps add equal weight
3. Find the outer product and add it to the result.
4. Repeat until all sequences are generated.

Here is the equivalent function:

```
import random
GROUPIDs = 2000
MINIBATCH_SIZE = 10000
TIMESTEPS = 100

def getMatrixOuter():
    result = np.zeros((GROUPIDs,TIMESTEPS))
    for x in range(100): #100 mini-batches each of size 10000 to replicate a sequence 
        batch_groupIDs = [random.randrange(GROUPIDs) for i in range(MINIBATCH_SIZE)] #10000 random sequences in range(0,GROUPIDs)
        counts = {k: 0 for k in range(GROUPIDs)}
        for i in batch_groupIDs:
            counts[i] = counts.get(i, 0) + 1
        vals = np.fromiter(counts.values(), dtype=int) #array of frequencies of GROUPIDs
        steps=np.ones((TIMESTEPS,)) #weight of each timestep
        np.add(np.outer(vals, steps), result, out=result)
    return result
```

Here is how it fared when timed:

```
%timeit getMatrixOuter()
1 loop, best of 3: 704 ms per loop
```

A possible benchmark could be evaluating it against a sequential add using `np.add.at()`

Here is a possible benchmark function:

```
GROUPIDs = 2000
MINIBATCH_SIZE = 10000
TIMESTEPS = 100

def getMatrixnp():
    result = np.zeros((GROUPIDs,TIMESTEPS))
    for i in range(int(1e6)):
        np.add.at(result, [random.randrange(2000) for i in range(1)], 1)
    return result
```

And here is how it fared on the same system:

```
%timeit getMatrixnp()
1 loop, best of 3: 10.8 s per loop
```

The solution certainly rests on some assumptions that may very well turn out to be false. Nevertheless, my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas, you can count the occurrence of each `batch_groupID` using the `groupby` method. Once performed, you can simply add this result to your initial matrix using the `add()` method (you need to ensure the axis is here is set to `0`). If you specifically need a `numpy.array`, then you can just use the `.to_numpy()` method on the DataFrame.

---

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(batch_groupIDs)
array = np.zeros((5,3))

#create a new series counting the occurrence of each index
group = s.groupby(s).count()

# leverage pandas add each count occurrence 
results = pd.DataFrame(array).add(group, 0).fillna(0).to_numpy()
```

which gives

```
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [2., 2., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.]])
```